# Running multiple copyjobs in powershell parallel

Tags: powershell, start-job

i try to speed up our copyjobs with an powershell script.

I iterate through a list of servers and try to start a job for each copy.

```
foreach ($i in $serverlist)
{   
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $i -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
        robocopy c:\temp d:\temp /MIR /R:0
    } -name CopyJob_$i | Out-Null
    }
}
```

The script is running fine, but it stops while copying till it gets to the next server.
I thought the new job will ran in the background and the script iterates to the next server.

Any idea why the loop stops at the robocopy-process?

Many thanks in advance

Stefan

Answer (score 2):

It should not be blocking execution on the copy itself, it will only block until `Test-Connection` completes and the job is started.

Right now your script is copying from `C:\temp` or `D:\temp` on the local machine every time.  You probably want this:

```
$jobs = foreach ($serverName in $serverlist) {
    Write-Host "Starting copy job for $serverName"
    Start-Job -Name "Copyjob $serverName" -ArgumentList $serverName -ScriptBlock {
      param($serverName)

      if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $serverName -Count 1 -Quiet)
      {
        robocopy "\\$serverName\`$c\temp" "\\$serverName\`$d\temp" /MIR /R:0
      }
   }
}

$jobs | Wait-Job
$jobs | Receive-Job
```

Comment: Hi Latkin, thx for your reply. I will try your code when i have some time and report if it works that way. You are right, i use variable servernames in my script but deleted the shares for security reasons. Only wanted to show what the script should do. I report soon :)

Comment: It works perfectly thanks! It seems a bit unlogic to start the jobs first and check afterwards if the connection is available to copy but all jobs start at once and i save a lot of time. :)

Comment: Note that if you're using relative paths, you should pass the base directory (the working directory, say) as an argument to `Start-Job`, then you can do something like `Set-Location $args[0]`